# Layout cycle detected - CommandBar Visibility

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Today I hit a *Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete.* exception in my UWP app while testing on a phone with 10586.29 preview build. It took me a while to figure out what happens, where and why, and I also found simple repro steps.

The simplest possible repro steps are:

- create a new project
- add a new CommandBar to BottomAppBar on the MainPage with Visibility.Collapsed
- show the CommandBar at some point (for example, when page loads)
- tap on ellipsis (imagine there are AppBarButtons and you wanted to see their labels)

Code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="BottomBar" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Page.BottomAppBar>

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BottomBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I hit this error while doing things a bit differently: with visual state triggers and visual states, because there are cases where I want my CommandBar to show, and there are cases where I don't, but it seems that it's easy to repro even with those 3 lines of code.

I am aware of workarounds (for example, start with visible CommandBar and then hide it if it's not needed), but I'm curious to know why it happens and if others are seeing it too? A weird bug?

Comment: Have you noticed if LayoutUpdated is getting fired over and over by chance?

Comment: The lines  of code shown, is that all that is needed in a blank project. Or do you have custom styles and Visual State changes within those styles. Cause based on the error something is causing the UI to recursively update its layout to no end. ( I have seen this in Silverlight when handling window size event etc)

Comment: @TYY yea SL is exactly what I was thinking. Although most of the time it was overcome just by doing the rest of the layout properly to accept the visibility change of the object in question.

Comment: That's all the code needed. I know what this error normally means, I just wouldn't expect it in this case. And it doesn't happen if I run it on desktop...